# countdown jquery current data

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have a countdown java script code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $('document').ready(function() {
            'use strict';
            $('.countdown').final_countdown({
                'start': 1452402000,
                'end': 1458298800,
                'now':  1452402000
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to set 'now' to `$.now()` or get the current date but when I put it

```
'now': $.now()
```

could any on help

Comment: seems there is no question in this post.......;P

Comment: Try `Math.floor($.now() / 1000)`

Comment: that's work @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `final_countdown` expects the time as [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since 1.1.1970) but 
`$.now()` returns milliseconds since 1.1.1970

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
        'use strict';
        $('.countdown').final_countdown({
            'start': 1452402000,
            'end': 1458298800,
            'now':  Math.floor($.now() / 1000)  // strip the milliseconds
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.now()` returns a time not date object. Instead you should use `Date()` object to get the date or use Date object to convert it to date.

From the docs:

> #### jQuery.now()
>
> **Description**: Return a number representing the current time.
>   *The $.now() method is a shorthand for the number returned by the expression (new Date).getTime().*

```js
var t = $.now();
var d = new Date(t);

$('pre')
        .append('$.now()::::::'+t+'<br>')
        .append('new Date(t)::::::'+d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```